# How to add storage-level caching between DynamoDB and Titan?

Tags: caching, amazon-dynamodb, graph-databases, titan, amazon-elasticache

I am using the [Titan/DynamoDB library](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend) to use [AWS DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) as a backend for my [Titan DB](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/) graphs. My app is very read-heavy and I noticed Titan is mostly executing query requests against DynamoDB. I am using [transaction- and instance-local caches](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/caching.html) and [indexes](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html) to reduce my DynamoDB read units and the overall latency. I would like to introduce a cache layer that is consistent for all my [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instances: A read/write-through cache between DynamoDB and my application to store query results, vertices, and edges.

[image: Caching between Titan API and DynamoDB]

I see two solutions to this:

1. **Implicit caching** done directly by the Titan/DynamoDB library. Classes like the `ParallelScanner` [could be changed](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/1.0.0/src/main/java/com/amazon/titan/diskstorage/dynamodb/iterator/ParallelScanner.java) to read from [AWS ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) first. The change would have to be applied to read & write operations to ensure consistency.
2. **Explicit caching** done by the application before even invoking the Titan/[Gremlin](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki) API.

The first option seems to be the more fine-grained, cross-cutting, and generic.

- Does something like this already exist? Maybe for other storage backends?
- Is there a reason why this does not exist already? Graph DB applications seem to be very read-intensive so cross-instance caching seems like a pretty significant feature to speedup queries.

Comment: I assume you've tried just making Titan's caches much bigger? What use case suggests introducing another level of indirection and latency?

Comment: That only solves the problem for one Gremlin server instance and not the cross-instance cache consistency problem.

Comment: @Sebastian: Reading from ElastiCache is roughly ten times faster than reading from DynamoDB. My application is extremely read heavy (read:write rate of about 100:1). If data does not exist in Titan's instance-local cache, I want to get it from ElastiCache instead of DynamoDB. The ElastiCache layer I am suggesting is across all EC2/Titan instances. If instance A updates a vertex it will invalidate/update the ElastiCache entries. Subsequent gets from instance B involving this vertex will update the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ParallelScanner is not the only thing you would need to change. Most importantly, all the changes you need to make are in DynamoDBDelegate (that is the only class that makes low level DynamoDB API calls).

Regarding implicit caching, you could add a caching layer on top of DynamoDB. For example, you could implement a cache using API Gateway on top of DynamoDB, or you could use Elasticache. Either way, you need to figure out a way to invalidate Query/Scan pages. Inserting/deleting items will cause page boundaries to change so it requires some thought.

Explicit caching may be easier to do than implicit caching. The level of abstraction is higher, so based on your incoming writes it may be easier for you to decide at the application level whether a traversal that is cached needs to be invalidated. If you treat your graph application as another service, you could cache the results at the service level.

Something in between may also be possible (but requires some work). You could continue to use your vertex/database caches as provided by Titan, and use a low value for TTL that is consistent with how frequently you write columns. Or, you could take your caching approach a step further and do the following.

1. Enable DynamoDB Stream on edgestore.
2. Use a Lambda function to stream the edgestore updates to a Kinesis Stream.
3. Consume the Kinesis Stream with edgestore updates in the same JVM as the Gremlin Server on each of your Gremlin Server instances. You would need to instrument the database level cache in Titan to consume the Kinesis stream and invalidate the cached columns as appropriate, in each Titan instance.